# Зависает оператор `await` в оконном приложении / программа висит при вызове Task.Result или Wait

Tags: c#, асинхронность, async-await, faq, c#-faq

Есть простой код

```
private static void Foo()
{
    Bar().Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Foo() done.");
}

private static async Task Bar()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Bar() done.");
}
```

Почему при вызове `Foo()` программа зависает и на консоль ничего не выводится?

Как этот код исправить?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38568/discussion-on-question-by-pavel-mayorov---await---).

Comment: А почему такого же поведения нет в консольном приложении?

Comment: @maxwell потому что там не установлен однопоточный контекст синхронизации

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Объяснение

Такое случается при работе в потоке UI. Дело в том, что все асинхронные вызовы, сделанные из потока UI, после выполнения "возвращаются" обратно в свой поток. И если этот поток заблокирован ожиданием окончания вызова - привет взаимоблокировка!

Разберем что происходит подробнее.

1. Вызывается метод `Bar`.
2. Начинается задача `Task.Delay(1000)`
3. Управление из метода `Bar` возвращается в метод `Foo`
4. В методе `Foo` начинается синхронное ожидание результата задачи, которое останавливает очередь сообщений.
5. Через секунду завершается задача `Task.Delay(1000)` в потоке таймера
6. Потоку UI посылается оконное сообщение, чтобы он возобновил выполнение метода `Bar`.

Но поток UI не может обработать это сообщение - ведь он висит в методе Foo! Все. Взаимоблокировка.

### Решение первое - сквозная асинхронность.

Все просто - если вызов `Wait()` вешает программу - надо избежать его. К примеру, сделать функцию `Foo` асинхронной:

```
private static async Task Foo()
{
    await Bar();
    Console.WriteLine("Foo() done.");
}

private static async Task Bar()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Bar() done.");
}
```

Разумеется, одно такое преобразование проблему не решает - ведь кто-то же вызывает `Foo()` и ему теперь тоже надо дождаться окончания ее работы. Поэтому это преобразование придется делать уровень за уровнем до самого верха.

Закончится все, скорее всего, обработчиком событий. Его придется сделать `async void`-методом. Если `Foo` - обработчик события, то это будет выглядеть так:

```
private static async void Foo()
{
    await Bar();
    Console.WriteLine("Foo() done.");
}
```

Но у таких методов есть проблема. Если вылетит исключение - оно либо уронит программу, либо вы про него никогда не узнаете. Поэтому всегда настраивайте обработчики неперехваченных исключений.

Для WinForms это делается так:

```
Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;

// ...


static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // Тут надо записать исключение в лог или показать MessageBox
}
```

### Решение второе - уйти в пул потоков

Если вывести исполнение метода `Bar` из потока UI - проблема также исчезнет. Для этого достаточно запустить `Bar` в пуле потоков любым доступным способом.

К примеру, вот так:

```
private static void Foo()
{
    Func<Task> f = Bar;
    f.EndInvoke(f.BeginInvoke(null, null)).Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Foo() done.");
}
```

Но этот код я привел только для примера. `EndInvoke/BeginInvoke` попросту выглядит некрасиво - так что лучше использовать более свежее API.

Наверное, наиболее красивый способ - вот этот:

```
private static void Foo()
{
    Task.Run(() => Bar()).Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Foo() done.");
}
```

Однако, при использовании `Task.Run` не удастся обойтись без замыкания, если `Bar` принимает хотя бы один параметр. Получается лишняя функция в цепочке вызовов. В этом нет ничего страшного для уже существующего кода - но при написании кода с нуля может возникнуть желание писать без дополнительных функций.

Нет ничего проще:

```
private static void Foo()
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Foo() inner task done.");
    }).Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Foo() done.");
}
```

### Решение третье - "побег из потока UI"

Оба прошлых решения были основаны на изменении кода `Foo` - но это будет менять код `Bar`. В этом есть некоторый смысл как в плане защитного программирования, так и в плане оптимизации. Дело в том, что асинхронный код быстрее выполняется в пуле потоков, чем в потоке UI - а потому большие куски кода, которые не работают с UI-контролами, из потока UI целесообразно вытаскивать.

Это можно было бы сделать обернув весь метод `Bar` в одну большую лябмду и воспользовавшиcь `Task.Run` - но красивым такой способ не назвать. Поэтому "побег из потока UI" чаще всего делают при помощи "хитрых" форм оператора `await`.

Самый простой вариант - это вот такой:

```
private static async Task Bar()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Console.WriteLine("Bar() done.");
}
```

Вызов `ConfigureAwait(false)` говорит продолжать исполнение в том потоке, где выполнилась задача, не возвращаясь обратно в поток UI. И такой код работает.

Но у `ConfigureAwait(false)` есть свои подводные камни. Во-первых, если задача была выполнена еще до вызова `await` - то реального переключения не произойдет! А значит, вот такой код работать не будет:

```
private static async Task Bar()
{
    await Task.FromResult(0).ConfigureAwait(false); // не работает
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Bar() done.");
}
```

Поэтому, `ConfigureAwait(false)` желательно дописывать к каждому вызову `await`, а не только к первому. Это значительно снижает визуальную красоту решения.

Во-вторых, вложенные асинхронные вызовы не защищены от взаимоблокировок, как это было с `Task.Run`! Особенно первый вложенный вызов, ведь он делается еще до переключения на поток пула.

```
private static async Task Bar()
{
    await Baz().ConfigureAwait(false);
    Console.WriteLine("Bar() done.");
}

private static async Task Baz()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);  // тут все равно повисло
}
```

Кроме того, код выше содержит и другую проблему. Задача `Baz()` выполнялась в потоке UI - а значит, вызов `await Baz().ConfigureAwait(false);` переключит нас ... на поток UI, а вовсе не на поток пула, куда мы так стремились!

Так что серебряной пулей `ConfigureAwait(false)` определенно не является.

Если есть желание окончательно переключаться в поток пула одной строчкой, могу предложить вот такой хелпер:

```
struct ContextSwitcher : INotifyCompletion
{
    private SynchronizationContext target;

    public static ContextSwitcher SwitchToBackground()
    {
        return SwitchToContext(null);
    }

    public static ContextSwitcher SwitchToContext(SynchronizationContext target)
    {
        return new ContextSwitcher { target = target };
    }

    public ContextSwitcher GetAwaiter() { return this; }

    public bool IsCompleted { get { return SynchronizationContext.Current == target; } }

    public void GetResult() { }

    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
    {
        if (target == null)
            continuation.BeginInvoke(continuation.EndInvoke, null);
        else
            target.Post(_ => continuation(), null);
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
private static async Task Bar()
{
    await ContextSwitcher.SwitchToBackground();

    await Task.Delay(1000); // Мы уже в потоке пула, и у нас нет никаких взаимоблокировок
    Console.WriteLine("Bar() done.");
}
```

### Решение четвертое - ожидание в своем контексте синхронизации

Зачем создавать отдельный поток - если все асинхронные продолжения можно выполнить в текущем? Надо лишь придумать как выполнять их во время ожидания...

К примеру, для этого можно установить свой контекст синхронизации, который будет ставить продолжения в очередь - а во время ожидания он будет из этой очереди продолжения исполнять.

Тут самое сложное - аккуратно обработать ситуацию поступления продолжения в очередь когда ожидание закончилось. Такое продолжение надо вернуть родительскому контексту...

```
class QueueSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext, IDisposable
{
    struct PostData
    {
        public SendOrPostCallback d;
        public object state;
    }

    private BlockingCollection<PostData> queue = new BlockingCollection<PostData>(new ConcurrentQueue<PostData>());
    private readonly SynchronizationContext parent = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    public QueueSynchronizationContext()
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(this);
    }

    public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        var q = queue;
        try
        {
            if (q != null)
                q.Add(new PostData { d = d, state = state });
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            // Мы можем сюда попасть после вызова CompleteAdding, если он произошел только что (гонка) или если измененная queue еще не видна в текущем потоке
            // ObjectDisposedException попадает сюда же
            q = null;
        }
        if (q == null) PostToParent(d, state);
    }

    private void PostToParent(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        if (parent == null)
            d.BeginInvoke(state, d.EndInvoke, null);
        else
            parent.Post(d, state);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        using (var queue_local = Interlocked.Exchange(ref queue, null))
            if (queue_local != null)
            {
                queue_local.CompleteAdding();

                foreach (var data in queue_local.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                    PostToParent(data.d, data.state);
            }

        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(parent);
    }

    public void RunLoop(CancellationToken token)
    {
        var queue_local = queue;
        if (queue_local == null) throw new ObjectDisposedException("QueueSynchronizationContext");

        try
        {
            foreach (var data in queue_local.GetConsumingEnumerable(token))
                data.d(data.state);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // Это нормальный выход из queue_local.GetConsumingEnumerable(token) при отмене токена
            return;
        }

        // А если мы добрались сюда - значит, кто-то нас уже закрыл
        throw new ObjectDisposedException("QueueSynchronizationContext");
    }

    public void WaitFor(Task task, int timeout = Timeout.Infinite)
    {
        using (var source = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout))
        {
            task.ContinueWith(_ => source.Cancel(), TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
            RunLoop(source.Token);
        }
    }

    public void WaitFor(Task task, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        using (var source = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout))
        {
            task.ContinueWith(_ => source.Cancel(), TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
            RunLoop(source.Token);
        }
    }

    public void WaitFor(Task task, CancellationToken token)
    {
        using (var source = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token))
        {
            task.ContinueWith(_ => source.Cancel(), TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
            RunLoop(source.Token);
        }
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
private static void Foo()
{
    using (var ctx = new QueueSynchronizationContext())
    {
        ctx.WaitFor(Bar());
        Console.WriteLine("Foo() done.");
    }
}
```

Замечание - внутри этого блока `using` *нельзя* использовать оператор `await` по понятным причинам. А вот внутри вызываемых методов (например, внутри `Bar`) - можно.

Кстати, нечто подобное использует Windows Workflow Foundation для "синхронного" исполнения рабочего процесса. Только там получается проще из-за особенностей работы (максимум 1 продолжение в очереди и никаких продолжений после завершения не остается гарантировано).