# Выполнение асинхронных методов параллельно

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Коллеги, помогите с кодом.

Пишу метод получения кастомного набора словарей из БД, который должен вызвать ряд асинхронных методов, дождаться выполнения каждого из них, сформировать "словарь словарей" и вернуть результат. Сигнатура метода следующая:

```
public async Task<IDictionary<LookupType, IEnumerable<RacetrackLookupBase>>> GetLookups(IEnumerable<LookupType> requiredTypes)
```

**Попытка 1.** 
Запустить сразу кучу тасков, тянущих данные из БД, положить в IEnumerable, сделать `await WhenAll()` и сформировать словарь из результатов тасков провалилась. EF не дает запустить вторую асинхронную операцию, используя тот же контекст данных, в котором запущена первая.

**Попытка 2**

```
return requiredTypes
            .Select(async t =>
            {
                IEnumerable<RacetrackLookupBase> lookup = await GetLookup(t);
                return new KeyValuePair<LookupType, IEnumerable<RacetrackLookupBase>>(t, lookup);
            })
            .ToDictionary(item => item.Result.Key, item => item.Result.Value);
```

Не собирается, получаю ошибку `"Contract extraction failed: async / iterator issue:"`. Почитал что есть такая трабла с контрактами, если cделать `async` метод который не использует `await` (хотя `await` вроде как используется внутри `Select`).

**Попытка 3**
Оставил почти тот же код. Только в конце костыль прилепил чтобы await "официально" присутствовал в методе

```
var dictionary = requiredTypes
            .Select(async t =>
            {
                IEnumerable<RacetrackLookupBase> lookup = await GetLookup(t);
                return new KeyValuePair<LookupType, IEnumerable<RacetrackLookupBase>>(t, lookup);
            })
            .ToDictionary(item => item.Result.Key, item => item.Result.Value);

    return await Task.FromResult(dictionary);
```

Получаю дедлок в момент вызова `Select()`. Поток зависает навсегда.

**Вариант 4**
Убрал LINQ и сделал по простому. Все работает

```
var lookups = new Dictionary<LookupType, IEnumerable<RacetrackLookupBase>>();
        foreach (var type in requiredTypes)
        {
            var lookup = await GetLookup(type);
            lookups.Add(type, lookup);
        }

return lookups;
```

Метод GetLookup() описан следующим образом

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<RacetrackLookupBase>> GetLookup(LookupType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case LookupType.AgeCategory:
                return await _db.LookupAgeCategories.ToListAsync();
            case LookupType.Distance:
                return await _db.LookupDistances.ToListAsync();
            ...
            default:
                return await Task.FromResult(new List<RacetrackLookupBase>());
        }
    }
```

Поясните плз, какие ошибки были допущены в вариантах? Какое решение наилучшее?

Comment: А что делает `GetLookup`? Там есть обращение к базе?

Comment: именно. Используя асинхронный интерфейс EF. Типа `ToListAsync()`

Comment: Окей, а какого типа `requiredTypes`? Это `IEnumerable` просто, да?

Comment: да, все верно. Сигнатура метода следующая `public async Task<IDictionary<LookupType, IEnumerable<RacetrackLookupBase>>> GetLookups(IEnumerable<LookupType> requiredTypes)`

Comment: Окей, сейчас напишу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Окей, смотрите. У нас есть ограничение, что методы `GetLookup` нужно вызывать параллельно. От него и будем плясать.

**Попытка 1** — так делать оказалось нельзя, запускать все `Task`'и одновременно не катит. Окей.

**Попытка 2**. Здесь давайте посмотрим, что произошло после первого `Select`'а. Отвлечёмся на секундочку от того, что на вас ругаются Code Contracts. У вас по сути получился ленивый `IEnumerable` тасков. Затем вы пытаетесь применить к ним `ToDictionary`. Это синхронный метод, поэтому он пробежит ваш `IEnumerable`, создаст таски, и вызовет на них `Result`. Если создание тасков по идее может оказаться строго последовательным (хотя гарантии нет), то уж вызов `Result` — плохо, вы дожидаетесь результата *синхронно*, блокируя текущий поток.

**Попытка 3**. Та же проблема, `await Task.FromResult(dictionary)` ничего не меняет.

**Вариант 4**. Ну да, правильно.

Смотрите, если вы хотите использовать LINQ, вам нужно по сути асинхронный `WhenAll`, но который обязательно запускает пробегает свой список *последовательно*. Например, такое:

```
static class TaskEx
{
    public async static Task<T[]> WhenAllSequential<T>(IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks)
    {
        var results = new List<T>();
        foreach (var t in tasks)
            results.Add(await t);
        return results.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Супер, спасибо. Варианты 2 и 3 теперь стали более понятными для меня. Однако до сих пор не совсем ясно почему в варианте 3 поток уходил в бесконечное ожидание. Даже если мы ждали результат синхронно, он должен был когда-то вернуться.

Comment: @nikita: Мне сложно сказать, не видя подробностей функции `GetLookup`. Ил может быть был race condition между различными Task'ами. Интересно было бы взглянуть на stack trace в момент бесконечного ожидания.

Comment: добавил к вопросу код метода `GetLookup()`. Уточню, что бесконечное ожидание в варианте3 стартует сразу после первого вызова `item => item.Result.Key`

Comment: @nikita Вот почему бесконечное ожидание при вызове `Result` случается: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/514529/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-await-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-task

Comment: @PavelMayorov т.е. `ConfigureAwait(false)` решит мою проблему?

Comment: @nikita: А почему бы не попробовать? Да, в некоторых случаях добавление `ConfigureAwait(false)` помогает.

Comment: @nikita да, решит. Но VladD привел вам более аккуратное решение.

Answer (score 5):

Имхо, но есть пара советов  (1) из идеалогии EF, если версия выше 4 и (2) по личному опыту:

1. Создавать контексты EF на каждую операцию. Если 6.0+ то вообще рекомендую. Они весьма легковесные, и это не будет тормозить, по сравнению с материализацией запроса.
2. Асинхронные вызовы оборачивать в отдельные классы-контексты операций (в вашем случае можно 1 generic, как понимаю), так будет легче отлаживаться. Т.е. если есть  уникальный запрос, то лучше весь асинхронный код объединить в контекст и вынести в класс-помошник, тем самым создав контроль над замыкаемыми объектами.

т.е. первый вариант был норм, только с созданным внутри таска контекстом, который создается-материализует-умирает в рамках отдельного потока.

2. (Дополенение)
   Это не решение, что бы не было неясностей. Это просто шаг в сторону single responsobility. Т.е. область ответственности за асинхронный вызов, разделение доступа к ресурсам несет отдельный логический элемент + никто не засунет в лямду какое-то поле "случайно" и не сделает его критической секцией без lock-а.Например, есть у тебя потребность в асинхронном выполнении запроса, который на вход получает object **t**. Понятно, что **t** становится разделяемым ресурсом между потоком вызова и таска. Так что важно обеспечить неизменяемость на время выполнения задания. Но в целом, будем считать что так и есть, и интерфейс блокирует модификацию объекта **t** "сверху". Так что перейдем к реализации задачи.

> ```
> return requiredTypes
>             .Select(async t =>
>             {
>                 IEnumerable<RacetrackLookupBase> lookup = await     GetLookup(t);
>                 return new KeyValuePair<LookupType, IEnumerable<RacetrackLookupBase>>(t, lookup);
>             })
>             .ToDictionary(item => item.Result.Key, item => item.Result.Value);
> ```

Проблема в данном случае в том, что
1. В лямду можно запихнуть что угодно из внутренностей класса.
2. GetLookup - метод класса. Пускай и приватный, но в целом живой и имеет доступ ко всем полям внутри класса и если разработчик обратиться к полю - получаем неконтролируемое разрастание критической секции и кучу багла на пустом месте.

Что предлагается сделать.
Определить класс-контекст. К примеру,

```
public class SomeAsyncContext:IDisposable
{
//в конструктор явно помещаем все, что необходимо для вызова асинхронного метода. Именно эти "объекты" и будут нашими разделяемыми ресурсами. При отладке ты сразу увидишь, что было замкнуто и легче определить сбой, имхо.
public SomeAsyncContext(object t, int a,int b)
{
  _t=t; _a=a;_b=b;
}

//Входных параметров нет, т.к. все уже внутри. Контекст легкий и на 1 операцию создается всякий раз новый и нет пока нужды параметры перезадавать, копя возможную ошибку состояния.
pubic async Task<Dictionary<object,object>> DoSome()
{
///делаем наши асинхронные дела. 
///Можно и просто return await GetLookup(_t);
///но в этом случае это будет уже внутренний метод и в единичном экземпляре.

}
```

Я бы сразу в лямде тело развернул. Получается, что мы не мешаем синхронный код с асинхронным, ставя вот такой логический "барьер" между ними. Опять же, это мой опыт, т.е. ИМХО.
Использование выглядит просто

```
using(var context = new SomeAsyncContext(t,a,b))
{
   result = await context.DoSome();
}
```

вот как-то так. И еще накинуть конрактов в контекст. Что бы сделать неизменяемыми внутри класса параметры.

Comment: Спасибо за советы. 

наша задача разрабатывается не первый день, поэтому трудно будет резко перейти на ваш вариант1. Уже есть куча оберток и классов , использующих 1 контекст, инжектируемый в конструктор. В принципе переписать можно, но надо все обдумать. А можете приложить пример кода для Вашего вариант2.

Comment: Всмысле дать пример оборачивания в контекст операции?

Comment: да, я не совсем понял Ваш вариант2. можно псевдокодом

Comment: @nikita дополнил текст.