# Ошибка при вызове _PartialView в асинхронном методе

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, асинхронность

Есть асинхронный метод

**ReportController.cs**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetRMschools()
        {
            Account account = new Account("chr_coko.pto@mail.ru", "***");
            var api = new MailRuCloud();
            api.Account = account;
            string schoolID = User.Identity.Name;
            var items = await api.GetItems($@"/Reports/{schoolID}");

            school school_current = schoolRepository.GetT(schoolID);
            List<RMschool> model = new List<RMschool>();            
            foreach (var file_name in items.Files) //e.g. file_name = "0001_201636.zip"
            {
                int report_code = Convert.ToInt32(file_name.Name.Substring(5, 6)); //e.g. report_code = 201636
                var ob = monit95Context.ReportMetas.Find(report_code);
                model.Add(new RMschool
                {
                    code = ob.code,
                    name = ob.name,
                    ProjectName = ob.ProjectName,
                    year = ob.year,
                    WWWref = $@"{school_current.ReportLink}/{file_name.Name}"
                });
            }
            return PartialView("_GetRMschools", model);
```

который вызывает частичное представление

**_GetRMschools.cshtml**

```
@using Monit95App.Models
@model List<RMschool>
<body>
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
            <tr>
                <th>Проект</th>
                <th>Отчет</th>
                <th>Учебный год</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach (var reportMeta in Model.OrderByDescending(x => x.code))
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@reportMeta.ProjectName</td>
                <td><a href="@reportMeta.WWWref">@reportMeta.name</a></td>
                <td>@reportMeta.year</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</body>
```

Теперь я пытаюсь получить это частичное представление в другом View

**Report.cshtml**

```
<h2>Отчеты</h2>
@Html.Action("GetRMschools")
```

При запуске выводит:

> Ошибка выполнения дочернего запроса для дескриптора
> 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'
>
> HttpServerUtility.Execute является заблокированным до окончания
> выполнения асинхронной операции.

1. Почему так происходит?
2. Как исправить?

Comment: сделайте Action который возвращает PartialView обычным (без async await) посмотрим что получится

Comment: @Ruslan_K к сожалению это не вариант - API MailCloud написан на асинхронных вызовах. Я  изначально так сделать пытался.

Comment: для теста можно проверить так `var items = api.GetItems($@"/Reports/{schoolID}").Result;`

Comment: @Ruslan_K я сделал так: на этой строке у меня программа зависает - уходит как-бы в "спякчу".

Comment: понятно, ну подождем что скажут более опытные участники SO :)

Comment: Про зависание: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/514529/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-await-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-task

Comment: Пожалуйста, сведите ваш вопрос к [mcve]. Сейчас он слишком сложный для понимания кем-то кроме вас самого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Причина*** из-за которой все не работало: если `action контроллера` вызывается из `View`, то такой вызов считается `дочерним`. А в `ASP.NET MVC 5` дочерние методы нельзя вызывать `асинхронно`. В ASP.NET Core вроде все как-то по другому, на сколько я правильно понял.

***Сложность*** задачи для меня заключается в том что: мне необходимо вызывать частичное представление `_RMschool.cshtml` на разных страницах моего приложения, а оно у меня `типизированное`. И поэтому перед его вызовом (_RMschool.cshtml) необходимо еще получить модель для нее.

***Решение***. Нашел [статью](https://cmatskas.com/update-an-mvc-partial-view-with-ajax/) в Интернете и с ее помощью вышел из ситуации:

**ReportController.cs**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Report()
{
    var model = await GetRMschoolList(User.Identity.Name);
    return PartialView("_RMschool", model);
}

public async Task<ActionResult> GetRMschoolPV(string _schoolID)            
{
    var model = await this.GetRMschoolList(_schoolID);
    return PartialView("_RMschool", model);
}

public async Task<List<RMschool>> GetRMschoolList(string _schoolID)  //GetViewModel       
{
    Account account = new Account("chr_coko.pto@mail.ru", "***");
    var api = new MailRuCloud();
    api.Account = account;            
    var items = await api.GetItems($@"/Reports/{_schoolID}");            

    school school_current = schoolRepository.GetT(_schoolID);
    List<RMschool> model = new List<RMschool>();            
    //du stuff
    return (model);
}
```

**Report.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Monit95App.Models.RMschool>

@{ Html.RenderPartial("_RMschool", Model);}
```

**_RMschool.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Monit95App.Models.RMschool>

    <body>
        <table class="table">        
            <thead class="thead-inverse">
                <tr>
                    <th>Проект</th>
                    <th>Отчет</th>
                    <th>Учебный год</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @foreach (var reportMeta in Model.OrderByDescending(x => x.code))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@reportMeta.ProjectName</td>
                    <td><a href="@reportMeta.WWWref">@reportMeta.name</a></td>
                    <td>@reportMeta.year</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </body>
```

Comment: Слишком сложно получилось. Выглядит так, будто вам не требуется два разных View.

Comment: Кроме того, что и почему произошло - так и не объяснено.

Comment: @PavelMayorov спасибо за замечание по поводу _не указания причины_. Ответ отредактирован.

Comment: @PavelMayorov по поводу _Выглядит так, будто вам не требуется два разных View_. Не совсем понял замечание. Можете более развернуто сказать?

Comment: У вас `Report.cshtml` используется только для включения `_RMschool.cshtml`. Можно было отображать сразу второй файл.