# Deadlock при использовании ExecuteReaderAsync()

Tags: c#, ado.net, async-await

Похоже что получаю Deadlock при использовании ExecuteReaderAsync(). Не могу понять что не так

```
Task task = ExecReader(tempList, query);
task.Wait();

async Task ExecReader(List<string> tempList, string query)
{            
     using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
     {
        try
          {                    
             sqlConn.Open();
             SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn);
             SqlDataReader reader = await sqlCmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

             while(reader.Read())
             {
                tempList.Add(reader.GetString(0));                               
             }
             catch(Exception e)
             { }                
          }            
     }
}
```

Доходит до `ExecuteReaderAsync()` и все, виснит наглухо.
Пробовал через `GetAwaiter()`, но в таком случае главный поток не дожидается выполнения задачи, и берет управление сразу после `ExecuteReaderAsync()`. А если через `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, то снова висит.

Comment: А вы и не делайте `Wait`, он же блокирует ваш поток. Делайте `await`.

Comment: @VladD, вы про это? http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: Да, именно про это. У меня даже эта статья упоминается в ответе.

Comment: Прилинкую: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/514529/106. Или дубль, @VladD?

Comment: @andreycha: Наверное, дубликат? // Ага.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы сделали <del>две</del> три ошибки, которые вместе приводят к данной проблеме.

Первая из них — вы пользуетесь синхронным `Wait`. Этот `Wait` блокирует поток до окончания задачи, а значит, поток будет висеть. Если внутри функции `await` захочет вернуться в данный поток (судя по всему, вы запустили `Task` в UI-потоке), он не сможет этого сделать потому, что поток заблокирован — deadlock.

Решение — не пользуйтесь `task.Wait();`, пользуйтесь `await task;`.

---

Вторая ошибка — вы в коде, который не рассчитывает на возвращение в исходный поток, не используете `.ConfigureAwait(false)`. Отсутствие `.ConfigureAwait(false)` заставляет код хотеть вернуться в UI-поток, если он был в нём запущен.

Пишите

```
SqlDataReader reader = await sqlCmd.ExecuteReaderAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

---

Третья ошибка — вы запускаете `Task`, работающий с базой данных и содержащий синхронные команды (`sqlConn.Open();`, например), в непонятно каком, может быть и в UI-потоке. Так делать нельзя, вынесите это всё в фоновый поток.

---

Итого:

```
Task task = ExecReader(tempList, query);
await task;
```

```
public Task ExecReader(List<string> tempList, string query)
{
    async Task Impl()
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            try
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn);
                SqlDataReader reader = await sqlCmd.ExecuteReaderAsync()
                                                   .ConfigureAwait(false);

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    tempList.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { }
        }
    }

    return Task.Run(Impl);
}
```

---

Ещё по теме: [Stephen Cleary *Don't Block on Async Code*](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: локальные функции :-) почему не `Task.Run(Impl)`?

Comment: @Grundy: Уже :)