# Как достать значение из async Task

Tags: c#, асинхронность, task

Есть вот такой код. Вопрос: как в `Main` достать значение `heart` из `ExampleTask()`?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication19
{

 class Program
   {

       static void Main(string[] args)
       {

       }
   }

 class Example
   {
       public async Task<string> ExampleTask()
       {
           UrbanService client = new UrbanService();
           var data = await client.Data("Mom");
           var heart = data.List[0].Definition;

           return heart;
       }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать оператор await для того чтобы дождавшись окончания асинхронной операции, получить возвращаемое ею значение.

```
string hart = await example.ExampleTask();
```

Имейте в виду, однако, три вещи.

1. Для того, чтобы было возможно использовать оператор await, при объявлении метода необходимо использовать оператор async.

   ```
   private async void MyMethod {
   ```
2. Весь код, который идет после строчки с оператором await выполняется асинхронно. То есть, выполнение метода MyMethod закончится на той строчке, на которой стоит оператор await, и управление будет передано в метод его вызывающий. Код, который вы напишете после оператора await, и который будет использовать переменную hart, выполнится только тогда, когда Task завершится.
3. Если метод Main не будет ожидать окончания задачи, то приложение завершится. В этом случае код после await может никогда не выполнится. Чтобы этого избежать, необходимо каким-то образом остановить выполнение метода Main. В этом случае, вам не подойдет решение с использованием оператора await. Придется дождаться окончания выполнения Task с помощью метода [Wait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635(v=vs.110).aspx).

   ```
   Task<string> task = example.ExampleTask();
   task.Wait();
   string hart = task.Result;
   ```

> - Второй нюанс зачастую не приводит к проблемам, но все равно о нем следует помнить. И если ваш код как-то не так работает, попробуйте
>     проанализировать как он будет выполняться учитывая этот второй нюанс.
>     Скорее всего, после этого сразу станет понятно как исправить код.
> - Третий нюанс не возник бы в приложении, в котором запущен UI поток
>     (WinForms, WPF), потому что такие приложения продолжают
>     функционировать даже после того, как ваш код прекратил выполняться.

Comment: Метод `Main` не может быть асинхронным.

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Известный своим блогом и книгой по асинхронщине Stephen Cleary предлагает специальный AsyncContext. [1](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html), [2](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext), [3](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx).

Comment: @maxwell может, начиная с C# 7.

Comment: Добавлю. Более того, в UI потоке использовать Wait() или Result [категорически нельзя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/514529/178779)