# Асинхронный и синхронный методы

Tags: c#, async-await

Имеется некий асинхронный метод:

```
public async Task<Foo> GetFooAsync();
```

мне также нужен его синхронный аналог

```
public Foo GetFoo();
```

Мне не очень хотелось бы полностью переписывать `GetFooAsync` и создавать на его основе синхронную версию метода. Достаточно ли будет сделать например так?:

```
public Foo GetFoo() 
{
    return GetFooAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

или у такой реализации "в лоб" есть подводные камни и так лучше не делать?

Comment: А ваш асинхронный метод "по настоящему" асинхронен? Может имеет смысл сделать наоборот?

Comment: А без `await` если просто вызывать разве он не синхронно будет выполняться?

Comment: @Anatol, без await он вернет `Task<Foo>`, а не `Foo`

Comment: Лучше сделайте синхронный метод основным, а потом сделайте на его основе асинхронный. Т.е. делайте вызов этого синхронного метода, и возвращайте его результат с помощью `Task<T>`

Comment: А что это за метод? Это библиотека? Где этот метод будет вызываться?

Answer (score 6):

Обратите внимание на вот этот вопрос: [Зависает оператор `await` в оконном приложении / программа висит при вызове Task.Result или Wait](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/514529/178779)

Там показана основная проблема таких вот вызовов `GetResult()`. И там же есть решение проблемы "но что делать если очень надо" через временный контекст синхронизации:

```
public Foo GetFoo() 
{
    using (var ctx = new QueueSynchronizationContext())
    {
        var task = GetFooAsync();
        ctx.WaitFor(task);
        return task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

Но это решение подходит только для однопоточных контекстов синхронизации, при выполнении в неограниченном пуле потоков правильнее будет вызвать `task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();` напрямую. В ограниченных же пулах потоков все еще сложнее - нельзя использовать `QueueSynchronizationContext` потому что он убьет параллельность - но нельзя и использовать блокирующее ожидание, потому что оно займет один поток.

Универсальным способом будет `Task.Run(() => GetFooAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, но этот способ смотрится странно (и опять-таки, несет проблемы когда пул потоков ограничен).

Наверное, проще всего просто выбрать только один метод и использовать только его. Но если вы пишите библиотеку - возможно, правильнее всего будет написать алгоритм два раза, и в блокирующем варианте, и в асинхронном.

Answer (score 4):

В общем случае нельзя просто взять и вызывать `GetResult()` / `.Result` в асинхронном коде, т.к. это с большой вероятностью приведет к дедлоку:

1. Ваш код ждет завершения GetFooAsync, блокируя поток.
2. Один из await внутри GetFooAsync ждет освобождения потока, чтобы выполнить на нем остаток GetFooAsync.

Возможные варианты обхода дедлока:

1. Использовать `.ConfigureAwait(false)` на всех асинхронных вызовах внутри вашего асинхронного метода ([и на вызовах внутри вызовов из вашего метода](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)). Тогда продолжнения для кода внутри метода будут выполняться на потоках из пула, без сохранения контекста.
2. Принудительно запускать ваш асинхронный метод в потоке из пула: `string code = Task.Run(GetFooAsync).Result`;

Но лучше так не делать, и тянуть асинхронность до самого верха.

Answer (score 0):

Так в лоб лучше не делать. И я настоятельно рекомендовал переписать отдельно на синхронный метод. Но уж если слишком лень и точно известно, что таск не уйдет в дэдлок, то можно попробовать так.

```
var task = MyAsyncMethod();
var result = task.WaitAndUnwrapException();
```

Но это не панацея, слишком много если в таком случае. Проще переписать синхронный отдельно.