# Используются ли в современном C# SynchronuzationContext или ContextBoundObject?

Tags: c#, .net

Собственно, вопрос.

Используются ли данные штуки в современном C#?

Как я понимаю, они нужны для того, что бы заставить работать с объектом в однопоточной манере, незаморачиваясь с `lock'ми`.

Я прочитал некоторые статьи, где писалось, что этих вещей лучше избегать, так как класс становится ограниченным и какой-нибудь стандартный `lock` профитнее. Так ли это или в каких сценариях это может пригодится?

На сколько я знаю, то только UI поток "из коробки" имеет свой `SynchronuzationContext` ?

Comment: «Я прочитал некоторые статьи, где писалось, что этих вещей лучше избегать, так как класс становится ограниченным и какой-нибудь стандартный lock профитнее.» — не читайте больше этих авторов. Спросите у них при случае, пробовали ли они написать многопоточный layout manager и почему, по их мнению, WPF однопоточный.

Answer (score 3):

В современном C# они широко используются "за кулисами".

Например, в WinForms можно использовать `SynchronizationContext.Send` и `SynchronizationContext.Post`, а можно их эквиваленты `Control.Invoke` и `Control.BeginInvoke`.

В TAP часто используется `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` при необходимости работать с GUI. То есть захватывается контекст и сообщения отправляются в него. Это проще и удобнее.

Comment: Еще такой вопрос: Есть такое понятие, как контекст потока. Я правильно понимаю, что оно устанавливается самой CLR по какой-то логике и на прямую с ним никто не работает? Как я на основании Synchronization атрибут.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Его устанавливает WPF. Ну и можно использовать самостоятельно, если необходимо, например, как `QueueSynchronizationContext` [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/514533/10105).

Answer (score 0):

ContextBoundObject используется в технологии NET.Remoting. Он есть "в коробке"

Comment: .NET Remoting сам по себе давным-давно устарел. Так что вопрос остаётся в силе.

Comment: Remoting хоть и устарел, но он есть "в коробке" Подключаешь пространство имен  using System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts; и пользуешся..