# HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync зависает

Tags: c#, многопоточность, async-await, httpclient

Всем привет! Не могу понять из-за чего происходит зависание в потоке, при использовании `HttpClient`.

Ниже асинхронный метод, в котором происходит зависание, при получении результата:

```
async static Task<T> Get<T>(string url) {
    using(var client = new HttpClient()) {
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd(Includes.UserAgent);
        var byteArray = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
        var @string = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(@string, new JsonSerializerSettings {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        });
    }
}
```

Еще ниже то, как я использую этот метод:

```
var result = Get<MyObject>(url).Result;
```

Вроде, ничего противозаконного не делаю. И таймаут выставлен, но, всё равно зависает и поток не может продолжить свою работу. Без какой-либо ошибки.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как разобраться или сразу исправить эту неприятность...

**UPDATE:**

Забыл добавить, что происходит это не сразу, а в неопределённый момент времени...

Comment: А ты уверен, что зависает? Если ответа от сервера не приходит, то ты не получишь ни ответ, ни ошибку. Для таких случаев у HttpClient есть свойство Timeout равной (по-умолчанию) 100 секунд, если ответа от сервера не приходит только после этого вывалится ошибка.

Comment: @John, 3 строчка в методе: client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

Comment: А зачем вам асинхронность, если в итоге вы запускаете "таску" синхронно? P.S. Это не многопоточность, ибо многопоточность - это создание нового потока путем написания чего то вроде `var thread = new Thread....; thread.Start();`, в вашем случаи это асинхронное (async/await) программирование.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ конкретно для этого места в коде нужно, чтобы отработало синхронно

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, к тому же, этот метод в отдельном потоке вызывается, может это влияет, поэтому и указал, возможно, это важно, не знаю, пока не могу принять причину такого зависания... Сорцы пока дебажить не стал...

Comment: А-а-а. Извиняюсь. Тогда поздравляю, у вас deadlock. Чтобы не расписывать [почитайте вот это к примеру](https://habr.com/ru/post/435666/). UPD: Забыл упомянуть, что это для UI характерно, но у вас судя во всему в UI это и используется, иначе вы бы не заморачивались await'ами.

Comment: Какой тип проекта? Не эта проблема случаем https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/514529/Зависает-оператор-await-в-оконном-приложении-программа-висит-при-вызове-task ?

Comment: @John о, очень похоже! Сейчас попробую. Проблема возникает спонтанно, иногда может пару дней всё нормально работать, а иногда, может прям сразу зависнуть, спасибо за пост, попробую ConfigureAwait сделать, думаю, что поможет. Отпишусь.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight спасибо! Очень похоже, сейчас попробую ConfigureAwait добавить.

Comment: @MarkKhromov, ещё есть подозрение, что там где Вы ждёте результат работы метода синхронно можно оформить так, чтобы оно работало всё так же асинхронно. Дело в том, что когда вы работаете с HTTP запросами полностью асинхронно, то нет такого потока, который бы залочился и ждал пока ему ответят. В Вашем же случае всегда есть такой поток. Это уже Вам принесло проблем. Я бы на Вашем месте убрал это синхронное ожидание. Уверен, можно это решить по другому.

Comment: @CasperSC спасибо! Подумаю над этим!

Comment: @John пока всё работает. Видимо, ConfigureAwait(false) действительно помог. Можете давать ответ, отмечу его как верный. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данный код вызвал deadlock, что характерно в UI приложении и в ASP.NET (но не в ASP.NET Core). Причину этого и подробные решения можно почитать [тут же на SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/514529/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-await-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-task). Дополнительно можно [почитать блог Стивена Клэри](https://blog.stephencleary.com/), который собаку съел на этом.

Заниматься копированием ответом не вижу смысла, но вкратце обозначу основные способы решения:

1) Простой - использовать async/await и не парится

```
var result = await Get<MyObject>(url);
```

**Плюсы**: всё работает, как нужно.

**Минусы**: синхронностью тут даже не пахнет.

2) Чуть сложнее - дописывать ко всем await'ам ConfigureAwait(false)

```
var byteArray = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

**Плюсы**: всё работает, как в асинхронном, так и в синхронном виде (с вызовом .Result/.Wait).

**Минусы**: данный метод придётся дописывать у всех await'ов в методе и во включённых методах. Так же будут проблемы со сторонними библиотеками, в которых такое решение не предусмотрено - они будут вызывать deadlock, как и тут.

3) С помощью своего контекста синхронизации - поможет избежать deadlock

Данный способ появился [очень давно](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/163ef755-ff7b-4ea5-b226-bbe8ef5f4796/is-there-a-pattern-for-calling-an-async-method-synchronously), так что можно воспользоваться или им, или той модификацией, что дан в ответе по первой ссылке.

**Плюсы**: позволяет не изменяя исходный код выполнить его синхронно.

**Минусы**: нет. Разве что чуть больше кода для вызова писать.

4) Пул потоков

```
var result = Task.Run(() => Get<MyObject>(url)).Result;
```

**Плюсы**: как и 3 позволяет запустить синхронно код без изменений.

**Минусы**: задача будет выполняться в отдельном потоке, что сделает невозможным прямую работу с UI.

Comment: Спасибо, помогли!