# Блокируется форма, при использовании HttpClient'а в async методе

Tags: c#, winforms

Использую async метод, чтобы получить html со страницы, но форма блокируется:

```
public partial class Test : Form
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    public async Task<string> GetSource(string url)
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage result = await httpClient.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }

    private async Task GetSourcePage()
    {
        string s = await GetSource("ссылка");
    }

    private async void StartButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            await GetSourcePage();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: `GetSourcePage().ContinueWith(t => t.Exception, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
` а где здесь `await`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, а нужно?

Comment: А вы попробуйте и расскажите о результате.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, а как запустить асинхронный метод из не асинхронного? await не работает.

Comment: А кто вам мешает сделать его асинхронным?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, так там ещё я хотел расположить диалоги подтверждения, а их можно использовать в асинхронных методах?

Comment: Можете, конечно, почему нет?

Comment: Что-то вы не договариваете. Показанный код не может блокировать форму.

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029988/sendasync-is-blocking-ui-thread

GetAsync использует метод SendAsync

К сожалению, по историческим причинам SendAsync не является чисто асинхронным. В частности, он синхронно выполняет поиск DNS и разрешение прокси. Итак, чтобы сделать это полностью неблокирующим, вам нужно будет обернуть этот вызов в Task.Run

Answer (score 0):

Используйте асинхронный вариант обработки события:

```
async void StartButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await GetSourcePage();
}
```

Comment: А как можно вставить туда работу с UI ведь, в асинхронных методах нельзя работать с UI?

Comment: @AimonZ. Я не уверен на 100%, но, кажется, можно, если вы уже находитесь в UI потоке. Вот если вы будете пытаться асинхронно работать с UI не из потока UI - тогда да, будут проблемы. Вот здесь подробно всё расписано, если что: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/514533/260769

Comment: @AimonZ. Конечно можно, но не напрямую, а через Invoke.

Comment: @ГеннадийП Invoke попросту выглядит некрасиво... И если вы уже в потоке UI (а ButtonClick ведь в потоке UI?), то Invoke не нужен по идее.

Comment: @CrazyElf Ну, сделать отдельный метод, в который передавать нужные параметры, в котором делать проверку на InvokeRequired от которого и запускать через Invoke либо напрямую.

Comment: @ГеннадийП Invoke - это что-то из прошлых веков до эпохи async/await )

Comment: не надо никакого Invoke. Если асинхронный метод стартовал из UI потока, то по окончанию  метода управление вернется в UI поток.

Comment: Благодаря самой из отвратительных ошибок, сотворенных Microsoft с .NET, раз в 10 лет, когда вы создаёте десктопное приложение, вам не нужно писать `.ConfigureAwait(true)`, так что исполнение после окончания асинхронной задачи возобновится в UI потоке. Плата за это несущественна: всего-то во всех остальных местах нам теперь нужно вечно писать `.ConfigureAwait(false)`, превращая красивый и понятный код в кашу

Comment: @Kir_Antipov у автора логика на эвентах от UI контролов, там скорее всего уже каша.

Comment: @tym32167, вот и я о чем. Кашу кашей не испортишь. Почему нельзя было сделать как раз возврат в оригинальный поток опциональным? Здесь от `.ConfigureAwait(true)` хуже уже не станет ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kir_Antipov так это ж значение по умолчанию, толку от него?

Comment: @tym32167, я говорю о том, что это значение по умолчанию - чудовищная ошибка :) Это я тут на Microsoft ропчу и рассуждаю, как могло бы быть хД

Comment: @Kir_Antipov а, я понял. Ну, не сказал бы, что это прям кричтичная ошибка. Невозможно все предусмотреть, когда выкатывашь такую объемную фичу как async-await. В моих прошлых проектах были такие проблемы, что эта просто казалось несущественной мелочью :)

Comment: @tym32167, предусмотреть все, конечно, нереально. Но ошибка все же критичная: постоянно с матами бегаешь по всей кодовой базе и расставляешь несчастный ConfigureAwait хД Очень надеюсь, что это в конце концов исправят, ибо, как по мне, проблема вполне себе заслуживает стать вторым в истории C# breaking change